# Funcion que transforma valor de un input

Tags: javascript

Tengo un input que recoge el valor estatura, y una función que transforma el valor:

- caso 1: si ingreso 123 le agrega un cero (0) y el resultados es 123.0 ESTA BIEN
- caso 2: si ingreso 123.4 lo deja tal cual. ESTA BIEN
  caso 3 : si ingreso 99  le agrega un cero (0) y el resultados es 123.0 ESTA BIEN
- caso 4 : si ingreso 1.23 me lo transformar a 123.0 ESTA BIEN
- Pero en el caso 5: si ingreso 99.4 me lo transforma a 994.00 . ESTA MAL. Debería dejarlo igual 99.4.

**ÉSTA ES MI FUNCION:**

```js
function format(input){
 var num = input.value.replace(/\./g,'');
 if(!isNaN(num)){
  if(num.length>3){
  num=num.substring(0,num.length-2)+'.'+num.substring(num.length-2);
  
  }
    console.log(parseFloat(Math.round(num * 100) / 100).toFixed(1));
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ejemplo" name="ejemplo"/>
<button type="button"  onclick="format(ejemplo)">Prueba</button>
```

Comment: El caso 2 falla también

Comment: Parece una especie de heurística para arreglar lo que el usuario introduce, pero con los ejemplos que has puesto no basta para hacerse a la idea: ¿Quieres los valores en centímetros y con un decimal? Yo intentaría comprobar que si el valor es mayor a, por ejemplo, 50 (un recién nacido), asumir que son centímetros, mientras que si el valor está entre 0.50 y 2.50 (por aceptar valores "humanos"), son metros y por tanto hay que multiplicar por 100 para pasar a cm. Cualquier otro valor lo consideraría erróneo.

Comment: Parece que lo que quieres es permitir que el usuario introduzca los valores en centímetros (123, 99, 123.4, etc) o en metros (1.23) y formatearlo para que se transforme a centímetros con un decimal. ¿Es eso correcto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que lo que quieres es calcular la altura en centímetros con un decimal, aunque permites al usuario introducir la cantidad en centímetros o en metros.

Una posible solución sería comprobar si el valor introducido es menor que 3 y multiplicar por 100 en esos casos (porque el dato introducido habrá sido en metros). A partir de eso, realizarías las operaciones que quieres, que realmente es ninguna... porque toFixed hará el redondeo por ti, por lo que el Math.round es innecesario.

```js
function format(input) {

  // leemos el numero
  var num = parseFloat(input.value);
  
  // si esta en metros lo pasamos a centimetros
  if (num < 3) {
    num = num * 100;
  }

  // mostramos el resultado en centimetros
  console.log(parseFloat(num).toFixed(1));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ejemplo" name="ejemplo" />
<button type="button" onclick="format(ejemplo)">Prueba</button>
```

Comment: Me funcion perfecto! muchas gracias por tu explicacion!